# PHP - socket_accept keep browser loading endlessly

Tags: php, sockets

Folks,

I´m trying do code a simple socket sample in PHP.
The following code seems to be working ok:

```
if(!($sock = socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0)))
{
    $errorcode = socket_last_error();
    $errormsg = socket_strerror($errorcode);

    die("Couldn't create socket: [$errorcode] $errormsg \n");
}

echo "Socket created \n";

// Bind the source address
if( !socket_bind($sock, "127.0.0.1" , 5000) )
{
    $errorcode = socket_last_error();
    $errormsg = socket_strerror($errorcode);

    die("Could not bind socket : [$errorcode] $errormsg \n");
}

echo "Socket bind OK \n";

if(!socket_listen ($sock , 10))
{
    $errorcode = socket_last_error();
    $errormsg = socket_strerror($errorcode);

    die("Could not listen on socket : [$errorcode] $errormsg \n");
}

echo "Socket listen OK \n";

echo "Waiting for incoming connections..... \n";
```

But when I add the line $client = socket_accept($sock); as just the next step, my aplication keeps in loading state for about 5 minutes and fails!

I researched stuff about but I can´t find a clue and much less a solution.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

From the documentation for [socket_accept()](http://php.net/socket_accept):

> If there are no pending connections, socket_accept() will block until a connection becomes present.

Do you have anything attempting to connect to the application?  If you don't, eventually socket_accept() will time out due to [default_socket_timeout](https://www.php.net/manual/en/filesystem.configuration.php#ini.default-socket-timeout).

Answer (score 0):

These are snippets from a working socket script of mine. It is skeletal, but you will catch the drift.

It's a blocking call unless you do something like this:

```
@socket_set_nonblock($sock);
```

And then loop continuously doing things with your connections and the data they send.

```
while(true){

    if(($newc = @socket_accept($sock)) !== false) {
        $con=1;
    }

    if($con==1){
        //There is a socket. Read data from it, write data to it or close it here:
        if($dataIn = socket_read($newc, 1024)){
            echo "Client: " . $dataIn  . "\r\n<BR>";
        }

        if($dataIn==""){
            socket_close($newc);
            return();
        }
    } 
sleep(1);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try running your script on CLI. should work like you want it to. Running it on the browser will eventually lead to a timeout.